# Remove GBA4iOS on iPhone 5, ios7b5

Tags: iphone, ios

I asked this in /r/applehelp and on regular StackExchange and nobody was able to provide a solution. About a month ago I gave into the craze to install the GBA4iOS app that was available without jailbreaking. When I installed it, it created a duplicate icon, which I would now like to get rid of (I already uninstalled the actual app). Has anyone else come across this issue? I looked all over Google and was unable to find anything other than restarting my phone, reinstalling the app & trying to uninstall it before the install process completed, and setting my time back. None of these options worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know how you feel. If you are talking about the phantom icon, I set my date back to normal, and shut my phone off for a few hours. This also delt with all my updating apps that were hung up from earlier that day!

Answer (score 0):

A lot has been changed over past few years. Just try this [GBA4iOS tutorial](https://gba4ios.online/) and you won't have any issue mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.